# Can I add annotations to object property assertion from jena?

Tags: jena, ontology, protege

I want to add an annotation (comment) to an object property assertion like the one below.

> Mobile → hasCamera → 8MP

I am able to get this specific assertion as a `Statement` object. Now I want to add annotations to this statement object, but there aren't any direct methods to do this with Jena. On the other hand I am able to easily achieve this in Protege tool. So is this just a feature of Protégé, or is there any possible way to do this with Jena?

Basically, I'm interested in this, to add a weight score to the property (link) between the two resources viz. Mobile and 8MP.

Comment: Another question, [Jena Ontology API how to retrieve axiom that attach annotation to a class property relation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17296209/1281433), involved accessing annotated axioms from the an ontology using the Jena API.  If you're already familiar with the Jena API, you might be able to just do the things there in reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jena, though it has some support for OWL via OntModels, is really an RDF-based API.  Statements in Jena are just a class representing the triple, and don't themselves represent a resource.  If you want to create annotated object property assertions, you'll need to have a look at [Section 2.3 Translation of Axioms with Annotations](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-mapping-to-rdf-20121211/#Translation_of_Axioms_with_Annotations) from the [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language Mapping to RDF Graphs](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/).  Specifically, it looks like [2.3.1 Axioms that Generate a Main Triple](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/#Axioms_that_Generate_a_Main_Triple) is what you'll want:

> If the row of Table 1 corresponding to the type of ax' contains a
>   single main triple s p xlt ., then the axiom ax is translated into the
>   following triples:
>
> ```
> s p xlt .
> _:x rdf:type owl:Axiom .
> _:x owl:annotatedSource s .
> _:x owl:annotatedProperty p .
> _:x owl:annotatedTarget xlt .
> TANN(annotation1, _:x)
> ...
> TANN(annotationm, _:x)
> ```
>
> This is the case if ax' is of type … ObjectPropertyAssertion ….

The referenced Table 1 appears earlier in section [2.1 Translation of Axioms without Annotations](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/#Translation_of_Axioms_without_Annotations).

So, to add the triple

```
Mobile hasCamera 8MP
```

with the annotation

```
hasWeightScore 6.7
```

you can use the following code:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.AnnotationProperty;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.Individual;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ObjectProperty;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.OWL;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.OWL2;

public class AnnotatedAxioms {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String ns = "http://example.org/";
        final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM );
        model.setNsPrefix( "ex", ns );

        final Individual mobile = model.createIndividual( ns+"Mobile", OWL.Thing );
        final ObjectProperty hasCamera  = model.createObjectProperty( ns+"hasCamera" );
        final Individual eightMP = model.createIndividual( ns+"8MP", OWL.Thing );

        final AnnotationProperty hasWeightScore = model.createAnnotationProperty( ns+"hasWeightScore" );

        final Resource axiom = model.createResource( OWL2.Axiom );
        axiom.addProperty( OWL2.annotatedSource, mobile );
        axiom.addProperty( OWL2.annotatedProperty, hasCamera );
        axiom.addProperty( OWL2.annotatedTarget, eightMP );
        axiom.addLiteral( hasWeightScore, 6.7 );

        model.write( System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
    }
}
```

which produces the following ontology:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:ex="http://example.org/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://example.org/hasCamera"/>
  <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://example.org/hasWeightScore"/>
  <owl:Axiom>
    <ex:hasWeightScore rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"
    >6.7</ex:hasWeightScore>
    <owl:annotatedTarget>
      <owl:Thing rdf:about="http://example.org/8MP"/>
    </owl:annotatedTarget>
    <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://example.org/hasCamera"/>
    <owl:annotatedSource>
      <owl:Thing rdf:about="http://example.org/Mobile"/>
    </owl:annotatedSource>
  </owl:Axiom>
</rdf:RDF>
```